# How to convert string into list of array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written code to generate all the dates for the given month:

```
nb_days = monthrange(2016, 2)[1]
dateDict = [datetime.date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, nb_days+1)]
outputItems = []
for dd in dateDict:
    outputItems.append(dd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

My output is something like this:

```
['2016-02-01', '2016-02-02', '2016-02-03', '2016-02-04', '2016-02-05', '2016-02-06', '2016-02-07', '2016-02-08', '2016-02-09', '2016-02-10', '2016-02-11', '2016-02-12', '2016-02-13', '2016-02-14', '2016-02-15', '2016-02-16', '2016-02-17', '2016-02-18', '2016-02-19', '2016-02-20', '2016-02-21', '2016-02-22', '2016-02-23', '2016-02-24', '2016-02-25', '2016-02-26', '2016-02-27', '2016-02-28', '2016-02-29']
```

I need get result something like:

```
[('2016-02-01', '0', '0', '0'), ('2016-02-02', '0', '0', '0'), ('2016-02-03', '0', '0', '0'), ('2016-02-04', '0', '0', '0'), .....]
```

Comment: You could try something like this, `outputItems.append(((dd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),)),)`
I don't understand what are '0's in `('2016-02-01', '0', '0', '0')` Its upto you how you add them.

Comment: '0' it is just a value. Thank you it helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `outputItems.append( (dd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '0', '0', '0') )`

```
nb_days = monthrange(2016, 2)[1]
dateDict = [datetime.date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, nb_days+1)]
outputItems = []
for dd in dateDict:
    outputItems.append( (dd.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), '0', '0', '0') )
```